# Multiprocess within flask app spinning up 2 processes

Tags: python, flask, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am building a flask app and need some background processes to run. I decided to go with multiprocess, but it's producing two processes when running within Flask. Does anyone know why this would happen? I've tested it on OS X and Ubuntu 12.04, with the same results. Here is an example:

```
import time
import multiprocessing
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
backProc = None

def testFun():
    print('Starting')
    while True:
        time.sleep(3)
        print('looping')
        time.sleep(3)
        print('3 Seconds Later')

@app.route('/')
def root():

    return 'Started a background process with PID ' + str(backProc.pid) + " is running: " + str(backProc.is_alive())

@app.route('/kill')
def kill():
    backProc.terminate()
    return 'killed: ' + str(backProc.pid)

@app.route('/kill_all')
def kill_all():
    proc = multiprocessing.active_children()
    for p in proc:
        p.terminate()
    return 'killed all'

@app.route('/active')
def active():
    proc = multiprocessing.active_children()
    arr = []
    for p in proc:
        print(p.pid)
        arr.append(p.pid)

    return str(arr)

@app.route('/start')
def start():
    global backProc
    backProc = multiprocessing.Process(target=testFun, args=(), daemon=True)
    backProc.start()
    return 'started: ' + str(backProc.pid)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=int("7879"))
```

Comment: I wanted to make a process async with running Process as a daemon using python 2.7.x. The problem is the return in the endpoint does not occur until the process is finished running, even though daemon is set to True. I'm running this on uWSGI, maybe that is why.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is a problem with the Flask auto-reload feature, which is used during development to automatically restart the webserver when changes in code is detected, in order to serve up the new code without requiring a manual restart.

In the guide, the `“app.run()”` call is always placed within an `“if __name__ == ‘__main__’”` condition, since the reloader is set to on by default. When using multiprocessing, this condition will result in false, so you have to instead disable the Flask autoreload when using it in a function like so:

```
def startWebserver():
          app.run(debug=True, use_reloader=False)
```

Link for reference:

http://blog.davidvassallo.me/2013/10/23/nugget-post-python-flask-framework-and-multiprocessing/

Comment: Awesome, that works. Thank you, I was banging my head against a wall with that

Comment: Be aware though, that deploying a Flask app using apache/mod_wsgi, using multiprocessing is not working at all or is very unreliable. Better use a task queue like Celery, Huey or Rq.

Comment: @ jjmurre : what problem are u facing for Apache? I'm planning to deploy my flask application with multiprocessing on apache.

Comment: @jjmurre did you try to deploy on apache? Did you get an issue?

Comment: @JuanPerez Deploying Flask with mod_wsgi using multiple processes is not a problem. In my remark on sep 12 '17 I was referring to the python multiprocessing module, not to mod_wsgi.